# can't get <p>'s text when useing python scrapy a website

Tags: python, scrapy

Here is the website's source html code:

```
      <p class="fc-gray">
           hello
       <span class="">2010-10</span> 
       <em class="shuxian">|</em>
             4.2                 
      </p>
```

I want to get the value 4.2.
The following is my code (carInfoDiv is a xpath element selector):

```
        miles = carInfoDiv.xpath("p[contains(@class,'fc-gray')]/text()").extract()[0]
```

in this way, I got the string 'hello', I have also tried string(.), but got all string in `<p>`, not the result I wanted. Please show me how to get only 4.2 in this situation.

Comment: Did you try `.extract()[-1]` ? You might also want to try `.extract()[-1].strip()` to remove the surrounding whitespace.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p48xt3bu/

Comment: @Cauterite,thx ,this works for me

Answer (score 0):

I don't know xpath very much. but regular expression may help you

this is not so elegant, but will work for you

```
>>> import re
>>> html = """
    <p class="fc-gray">
       hello
    <span class="">2010-10</span>
    <em class="shuxian">|</em>
         4.2
    </p>
"""
>>> search = re.search('em>[\n\s]*(?P<result>[\d.]+).*', html, flags=re.DOTALL)
>>> if search:
...     print(search.group('result'))
...     
4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are after the last text child of the `<P>` element, so you can add a `[last()]` predicate to your XPath expression:

```
>>> import scrapy
>>> s = scrapy.Selector(text="""      <p class="fc-gray">
...            hello
...        <span class="">2010-10</span> 
...        <em class="shuxian">|</em>
...              4.2                 
...       </p>""")
>>> s.xpath('.//p[@class="fc-gray"]/text()[last()]')
[<Selector xpath='.//p[@class="fc-gray"]/text()[last()]' data='\n             4.2                 \n     '>]
>>> s.xpath('.//p[@class="fc-gray"]/text()[last()]').extract_first()
'\n             4.2                 \n      '
>>> s.xpath('.//p[@class="fc-gray"]/text()[last()]').extract_first().strip()
'4.2'
>>>> # alternative using XPath's normalize-space() to do the whitespace stripping
>>> s.xpath('normalize-space(.//p[@class="fc-gray"]/text()[last()])').extract_first()
'4.2'
```